# In java, a composite object cannot contain other objects. what does it means?

Tags: java

I am confused with the following statement . Could anyone help me in understanding the following statement?

> In java , a composite object cannot contain other objects. It can only have references to its constituent objects. Constituent Objects can be shared between objects and their lifetime can be independent of the lifetime of the composite object.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In other languages, such as C++, an Object can be thought of as containing another object.  If an object of class A contains an object of class B, A will be bigger than B.

In Java you only have references from one class to another (a part from inheritance) If A references B, it doesn't matter how big B is, it doesn't influence the size of A.

Answer (score 4):

It means that in Java, **unlike in languages such as C++**, an object cannot contain other objects, only references to them.

This means that there is no practical difference between the concepts of composition and aggregation. In a composite an object's lifespan is confined within the lifespan of the containing object and typically the containing object creates the contained one. In an aggregate there's more freedom.

Answer (score 3):

Consider something like this:

```
class Foo {
}

class Bar {
    Foo my_foo = new Foo();
}
```

`my_foo` is a **reference** to a `Foo` object, it's not the object itself.  The `Foo` object itself is not directly tied to the "enclosing" `Bar` object.

Answer (score 2):

Object-typed variables in Java are references that point to objects that are allocated and live on the heap.

You need to understand the consequences of this design choice: it means that if the object on the heap is modified, then all objects that refer to it see that change.

So if you have a situation like this, the code that creates the object that address refers to can change the private state of Person by modifying the address:

```
class Person {
    private String name; // Strings are immutable; that is important
    private Address address; // Address as written below is mutable

    public Person(String n, Address a) {
        this.name = n;
        this.address = a;
    }
}

class Address {
    private String street;
    private String city;
    private String stateOrProvince;
    private String postalCode;

    public Address(String street, String city, String stateOrProvince, String postalCode) {
        this.street = street;
        this.city = city;
        this.stateOrProvince = stateOrProvince;
        this.postalCode = postalCode;
    }
    // add getters and setters, etc.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If we call the method of super class by creating the object  in sub class  or by using reference of the super class object then there may be no difference between reference and aggregate.